# pasting screenshots into org, on Windows

Tags: org-mode, microsoft-windows, clipboard

I've got the following code, which creates a filename, inserts a link to it at point, and should also save the current image in clipboard to disk at that filename/location.
It used to work, but something broke recently, and I can't figure it out.
The link is inserted correctly - the saving of the file is broken somehow.

Would greatly appreciate your help!

```
(defun my/org-screenshot ()
  "Take a screenshot into a time stamped unique-named file in the
   same directory as the org-buffer and insert a link to this file."
  (interactive)
  (setq filename
        (concat
         (make-temp-name
          (concat (buffer-file-name)
                  "_"
                  (format-time-string "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_")) ) ".png"))
(shell-command (format "powershell.exe -Command \"Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; $clipImg = [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::GetImage(); $clipImg.Save('%s')\"" filename))
  (insert (concat "[[file:" filename "]]"))
  (org-display-inline-images))
```

it doesn't render well in the comment, but the error I get (even when running it from powershell itself, but with `powershell -Command...`) is:

> At line:1 char:113
> ... .Drawing.Bitmap = [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::GetImage(); Syste ...
> ~
> An expression was expected after '('.

This is the actual command being run:
`powershell.exe -Command "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; $clipImg = [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::GetImage^(^); $clipImg.Save('test.png')"`

Comment: I get this error :
`At line:1 char:92
+ ... Windows.Forms;  = [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::GetImage(); .Save ...
+                                                                  ~
An expression was expected after '('.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedExpression
`

Comment: Have you tried executing the `powershell.exe` command with all its arguments in a Command window? Does it work there? I'm not sure how `shell-command` does things on Windows, but the above should give you a clue about what's going wrong.

Comment: so actually the command itself (inside the double quotes) works well, but using the entire form gives me again (edited the main question with the error)

Answer (score 0):

ok, here's the solution, though I'm not sure why it works :)

```
(defun my/org-screenshot ()
  "Take a screenshot into a time stamped unique-named file in the
   same directory as the org-buffer and insert a link to this file."
  (interactive)
  (setq filename
        (concat
         (make-temp-name
          (concat (buffer-file-name)
                  "_"
                  (format-time-string "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_")) ) ".png"))
  (powershell (concat "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; $clipImg = [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::GetImage(); $clipImg.Save('" filename "')"))
  (insert (concat "[[file:" filename "]]"))
  (org-display-inline-images))

(defun powershell (script)
  "executes the given script within a powershell and returns its return value"
  (call-process "powershell.exe" nil nil nil
                "-Command" (concat "& {" script "}")))
```